AWS CLI - aws s3 rm --recursive command not working in powershell script but works via git bash and powershell command line
Git Bash - working (able to delete folder):
aws s3 rm --recursive s3://abcorigin/A1234H/

Powershell command line console - working (able to delete folder):
& aws s3 rm s3://abcorigin/A1234H/ --recursive

However, if I try to put it in .ps1 script file (as I have many folders to delete) and try to run it, it fails without any output. I tried putting escape characters as suggested in various online resources but no luck:
'& aws s3 rm "s3://abcorigin/A1234H/" –-recursive'

Output - same command gets printed:
& aws s3 rm "s3://abcorigin/A1234H/" --recursive

PS: aws configure is working fine and I have given the necessary permission via:
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser
Value: RemoteSigned
'& aws s3 rm "s3://abcorigin/A1234H/" –-recursive'

If I remove ' from beginning and end it throws missing terminator error.
Powershell version:
$PSVersionTable.PSVersion

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      1      22621  4111


Why are you using the invocation operator (&) in the first place? Generally that's only needed if the command you're executing contains whitespace.

Small hint: If you are copying commands from a web page/document rather than typing them yourself, make sure the double hyphen -- is using actual hyphens rather than m-dashes that are often caused by word processors. Your code included some of them before I reformatted your Question.

The command at the console is the same as what you would put in a script. There's no special syntax for scripts; it's the same as what you would use at the console.

Thanks @JohnRotenstein and Bill_Stewart. Even after these hints, the issue is still there. Please advise.
